# How to copy formatted code to clipboard in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, is it possible to copy selected code to the clipboard with the syntax highlighting?  I want to be able to paste into a Word doc or e-mail.

Regular Visual Studio does this by default (it puts both text and RTF formats on the clipboard).

I see that I can "Toggle Developer Tools" and locate the div (with class="view-lines") that has the code, so maybe there is a way to use that chunk of html, but I don't see an easy way to just copy the formatted code and paste into Word or an e-mail.

Comment: You cannot do this currently, just copying the HTML will not work as you need all the CSS for the highlighting as well. It's a valid feature request if you want to make an issue at https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues

Comment: Thanks Daniel.  I added a github issue (https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3518).

Comment: Resolved on [1.10 version](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_10#_copy-with-syntax-highlighting).

Comment: Just a normal copy and paste worked for me. I'm on Mac using VSC 1.52.1.

Answer (score 35):

According to the 1.10 changelog : https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_10#_copy-with-syntax-highlighting

It is now possible with that command : `editor.action.clipboardCopyWithSyntaxHighlightingAction`

Type/paste it in command box (`ctrl+shift+p` or `F1`)

Comment: Doesn't work: copy HTML from Visual Studio Code, start `C:\Program Files\Windows NT\Accessories\wordpad.exe`, paste and get non-formatted text.

Comment: same here. i type editor.action.clipboardCopyWithSyntaxHighlightingAction, then try copying from the vscode terminal to wordpad and it's unformatted. @Mistermatt, did you try it for yourself?

Comment: Nowadays the command is called "Copy With Syntax Highlighting" (1.43.*)  Pasting to Wordpad doesn't work (=unformatted), but to Word it works (Paste Options: Keep source formatting)

Comment: Hmm...this doesn't seem to work when copying from an RDP session to a local window

Answer (score 12):

Use the command "Copy With Syntax Highlighting".

> 1. Highlight the code
> 2. `Ctrl + Shift + p` to open the Command Palette
> 3. Type / Select `Copy With Syntax Highlighting`

It is available since VS Code v1.43 (Feb 2020), as @robert4 mentioned in comment.

Comment: For future reference (to this already ancient answer): using this Palette you are not setting a property in VSCode; it is a command in itself (makes sense), so you  should *first* select the part you want to copy and *then* issue this command.  I don't see why this is not the default copy-behavior, TBH.

Answer (score -1):

Ran into this question as I was trying to copy and paste with syntax highlighting from **Visual Studio (not Code)**. As far as I see, it is not possible OOTB.

I am using **Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 (v16.7.4)**, trying to copy C# code (tried CSHTML also).

BUT, I found [this article](https://thisdavej.com/how-to-copy-visual-studio-code-with-syntax-highlighting-to-other-applications/), which seemed to indicate that **Visual Studio Code** OOTB would *Ctrl+C Ctrl+V* right into an Outlook email or Word document without a plugin or fancy keyboard shortcut, and I was successful!

I am using **Visual Studio Code v1.49.2**, and copying C# code. Copying CSHTML also worked.

Answer (score -1):

I took the suggestion above, went to the command pallet, clicked on the clog to the right, and used ctl + c for the key bindings. Now, when I copy from VSCode to OneNote, I get the source formatting. It works!